# Using delegate() for dynamically added container

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you explain me how I can catch click event for dynamically added checkbox? I can do it, but can't understand one thing - why can't use delegate() for dynamically added container for checkbox. Code is like that:

```
<p style="blue">
<input type="checkbox" name="first" />
</p>
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TFAvG/).

In this example I never catch the message ".blue CLICK" but only see "#ch CLICK".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example - When the delegate is initialised the p element with the blue class does not exist. The container you setup the delegate on needs to exist in the dom.

Comment: But from documentation I read:

"Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future". 

"or in the future" means (as I understand) that it helps me to catch events for dynamically added elements.

Comment: The child elements do not need to exist at setup. The container does.

Comment: So its useless to setup delegate() to child element?

Comment: @dizers. No the children dont need to exist. Bind to document if all else fails as that will always be there!